# find an algorithm that calculates the transitive closure of a directed graph using O(n 4 ) time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, floyd-warshall

for an assignment I am asked by to find find an algorithm that calculates the transitive closure of a directed graph using O(n 4 ) time. We already learned about the floyd warshall algorithm, which is a lot better, so can someone help me create one that runs in O(n4) time? is there such an algorithm?

I know it seems dumb of a question. I dont really understand why we are being asked to find the slower way to do it.

Comment: Define transitive closure for graphs. Do you mean `Q = { (u,v) | (u,v) is an edge OR there is w such that (u,w),(w,v) is in Q }` ?

Comment: T^(k)=t^(k)_ij is an n × n bit matrix, where t^(k)_ij = 1 if there exists a path from i to j where the intermedia vertices are from {1, 2, . . . , k}; otherwise, t^(k)_ij = 0. is what im using.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to actually achieve a set of triplet `(i,j,k)` where `(i,j,k)` is in `T` if and only if there is any path (might not be shortest) from i to j of length k? This is a different question then I was thinking originally, where you don't care for the length of the path - only its existence. If so - the problem is reduceable from Hamiltonian Path problem, and there is no known polynomial solution to it. Can you clarify it?

Comment: no ur solution below is what im lookin for. not lookin for a set of triplet

Comment: I just thought I'd note that your lack of capitalization and punctuation is something of a turn-off. You're a smart person engaging with difficult problems, do yourself the favour of not exposing yourself to the stereotypes accompanying your language choices.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, Richard.

Comment: Oh, and I almost forgot: Getting the transitive closure can actually be done in `O(n^2)`, by finding maximal strongly connected components, and doing topological sort on the resulting DAG. It is easy to see you cannot really get better then it, since there are O(n^2) pairs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Floyd Warshall is `O(n^3)`, and since `O(n^3)` is a subset of `O(n^4)`, it is also `O(n^4)`.**

Thus, by setting a new graph `G'=(V,E',w')` where `E' = V x V` (clique, complete graph) and `w'(u,v) = 1 if (u,v) is in E, otherwise INFINITY` - by using Floyd-Warshall algorithm, each pair `(u,v)` that ends up with a value less then infinity is in the closure.

---

**A Theta(n^4) solution:**

```
Q <- E (init) #(Q is a set)
for i from 1 to n:
   for each v in V:
     for each w in V:
        for each u in V:
            if (v,w) is in Q and (w,u) is in E:
               Q <- Q U {(v,u)}  #add (v,u) to Q
```

Complexity is trivially `Theta(n^4)`, we only need to show it indeed finds the transitive closure.

By induction:

1. For shortest path of length 1 from u to v it is the base clause,
   since (u,v) is in E.
2. For each `k`: 

   Each pair `(u,v)` with shortest path of length `k>1` - there is `w` such that there is a path `u -> ... -> w`, and an edge `(w,v)`. From induction hypothesis, in previous iterations we added `(u,w)` to `Q`, and thus the condition will yield true, and we will add `(u,v)` to the resulting set `Q`.

Similary show that if some pair `(u,v)` was added to Q, then there is a path `u->..->w->v`, and thus it was rightfully added.

---

**A second `Theta(n^4)` solution:**

Set `G'` as described above, and for each vertex `v` in `V` run Bellman Ford from `v`.

Each run of BF is `Theta(n^3)`<sup>1</sup>, running it `n` times is `Theta(n^4)`

---

(1) Technically it is `O(VE)`, but for none sparse graphs `E` is in `Theta(V^2)`

Answer (score 2):

The Floyd-Warshall Algorithm for transitive closure looks like:

```
int dist[N][N];  // For some N
int i, j, k;
// Input data into dist, where dist[i][j] is the distance from i to j.
// If the nodes are unconnected, dist[i][j] should be infinity

for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ )
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
   if(dist[i][k] && dist[k][j])
      dist[i][j] = 1;
```

Note the order of the indices used: they are ordered this way to preserve an optimal substructure property. If we instead reorder them as below, that property is violated:

```
  for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
  for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
  for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ )
    if(dist[i][j] && dist[j][k])
      dist[i][k]=1;
```

The result of violating the property is that the transitive closure paths grow (at worst) only one link in the O(n^3) iterations above. In order to ensure that they transitive closure paths grow all the way, we need to keep iterating until they stop growing:

```
do{
  something_done=false;
  for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
  for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
  for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ )
    if(dist[i][j] && dist[j][k]){
      dist[i][k]=1;
      something_done=true;
    }
} while (something_done);
```

If the outer loop is in O(N), then the algorithm itself is in O(N^4).

Unfortunately, it may not be possible to (easily) show that the outer loop has that property, since it is particular to the data.